# Can't Install TensorFlow Via Pip

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to install TensorFlow via pip in the command line. I have satisfied all the requirements but all I get when executing `pip install tensorflow` is

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

I also tried to install manylinux2010 but I get the same output. I'm running Windows 10 on a laptop with Python v. 3.8.5 installed. Pip version is 20.2.3 If you could help me that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please tell your PC specs. By the way can you try `pip install tensorflow==13.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow as of Aug-13-2018 supports, Python 3.6.x, and only the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
```

Change `python3` to `python` according to your configuration. Change py3 to py2 in the URL if you are using Python 2.x.

A list of different versions if someone needs: https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow

A list of URLs for the available wheel packages is available here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location

Answer (score 0):

I believe tensorflow only supports python version 3.6.x I would recommend you to create virtual environment with python version 3.6.x with conda:

```
conda create --name venv python=3.6.5
conda activate venv
```

Then try to install tensorflow it should work

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is supposed to work for stable versions of python only.
One option is to use either `python 3.7` or you can try [installing tensorflow by building from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes installation of tensorflow fails because the gpu doesn't support it. In this case you should look for a version of CUDA supported by your video card.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus